# What will Lightsail charge if my instance only runs for 5 minutes?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I know that pricing for the AWS Lightsail instances are based on the amount of hours they run. However, if I only run an instance for 10 minutes and then delete it, am I still billed for an hour minimum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/faq/)

> What is a Lightsail plan?
>
> Also referred to as a bundle, a Lightsail plan includes a virtual
>   server with a fixed amount of memory (RAM) and compute (vCPUs),
>   SSD-based storage (disks), and a free data transfer allowance.
>   Lightsail plans also offer static IP addresses (5 per account) and DNS
>   management (3 domain zones per account). **Lightsail plans are charged
>   on an hourly, on-demand basis, so you only pay for a plan when you're
>   using it.**

Based on this I believe the minimum charging time is one hour. If you want shorter you can use [EC2 which is per-second](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-per-second-billing-for-ec2-instances-and-ebs-volumes/).